# Chrome Packaged Apps: Check if 'Experimental Extension APIs' flag is enabled

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I happen to be working on some changes to [a proof-of-concept app I already have in the Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wake-up/lbbcfplbfbmimpnlammmeaheakhcogke) that are indeed awesome: the `chrome.app.window.create()` option that allows developers to bake Aura/Ash transparency into their windows (right now, there's actually a static image set as the app's background). Since the app is only really meant for Chrome OS users anyway, the fact that it depends on Ash to function is really no problem on my part.

However, there's a stumbling block. Thank God it doesn't actually require the `experimental` permission, as that would ban an update to the app from entering the CWS, but still, the only way the window will truly be transparent is with the Experimental APIs flag enabled. So, is it possible to check if the Experimental Extension APIs are enabled to fall back on the app's packed wallpaper in case they aren't?

Answer (score 1):

This API is still being developed, and has not completely gone through our API approval process, so it might change. That's why it is listed as experimental :) You shouldn't ship an app relying on this API in its current state as it will likely break.

Having said that, part of the plan is to allow you to detect, via the API, whether the feature is available. This is so your app will be able to work on platforms like Windows XP that won't support transparency.

Comment: Since every other OS happens to have native power management tools to begin with, the app I linked to in the main section — which happens to be a power management app that uses chrome.power for most of its functionality — only really has a use case on Chrome OS to begin with, and in fact, it calls management.uninstallSelf if installed on something other than a Chromebook. So, the fact that transparency only works in Aura/Ash makes no difference... Then again, I did fix the problem temporarily by simply using "if (chrome.experimental == undefined)".